# Whats wrong with this MYSQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, subquery

```
    SELECT * FROM event JOIN user ON event.event_user_id=user.user_id
  WHERE ((event.event_date BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-04-01' ) 
    AND user.user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM user_map 
      WHERE (user_map.user_id_map=1 AND user_map.user_relation<=7)));
```

This is working fine in Toad/MYsql but fails when I do it with prepared statement in java + mysql driver as

```
    SELECT * FROM event JOIN user ON event.event_user_id=user.user_id
  WHERE ((event.event_date BETWEEN ? AND ? ) 
    AND user.user_id in (SELECT user_id FROM user_map 
      WHERE (user_map.user_id_map=? AND user_map.user_relation<=?)));
```

...

```
pstmt.setDate(1, <sqlDate>);
pstmt.setDate(2, <sqlDate>);
pstmt.setLong(3, <int>);
pstmt.setLong(4, <int>);

pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: "fails" is pretty vague... care to tell us what actually happens? Does it execute but return the wrong results? Give an error message? If it's the latter, what's the error message?

Comment: It would be also useful when your post your last code snippet really as it is. There are some errors that you can make with passing the parameters to the preparedstatement methods which we cannot check when you substitude the real parameters by <sqlDate> and so on...

Comment: This is what I was getting.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(user_map.user_id_map=208 AND user_map.user_relation<=10)))' at line 1
But I also figured out the problem !! I had missed a space between "user_map" and "WHERE" in the last line because of Eclipse's automatic string wrapping to next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not closely related to problem but the query is not efficient and can be improved

```
SELECT * 
FROM   event 
       JOIN USER 
         ON event.event_user_id = USER.user_id 
       JOIN user_map 
         ON user_map.user_id = USER.user_id 
            AND user_map.user_id_map = 1
            AND user_map.user_relation<=7 
WHERE  ( event.event_date BETWEEN '2011-03-01' AND '2011-04-01' ) 
GROUP  BY USER.user_id
```

you need indexes on

- (event.event_user_id,event.event_date)
- (USER.user_id)
- (user_map.user_id, user_map.user_id_map,user_map.user_relation)

Comment: Thank you !! It was just a space issue I had before I posted it here. But I'm glad I did. You querry seems to be a lot effecient and easier to read as well. Everyday learning !! Thanks again